# How to Define an Azure Custom Connector Trigger Using Attributes in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, swagger, azure-logic-apps

I am working on integrating an Azure custom connector with my ASP.NET Web API, and I need some guidance on setting up a trigger using attributes. While I have successfully mapped an action to a Swagger/OpenAPI definition which imports seamlessly into the custom connector (see code snippet below), I am unsure how to go about defining a trigger similarly.

Here's the code snippet where I defined an action successfully:

```cs
[HttpPost(Name = "CreateClient")]
[SwaggerOperation(Summary = "Creates a new client", Description = "This endpoint creates a client")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ApiResponse<Client>), (int)HttpStatusCode.Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ApiResponse), (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateClient([FromBody] Client client)
{
    //... method implementation
}
```

Moving on to defining a trigger, here's what I've attempted so far:

```cs
[HttpPost(Name = "RegisterListener")]
[CustomKeyValue("x-ms-trigger", "single")]
[SwaggerOperation(Summary = "IBAN Changed Trigger", Description = "This endpoint triggers when an IBAN changes!")]
[SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, "Success!", typeof(ApiResponse<IBANChange>))]
public IActionResult RegisterListener([FromBody] RegisterListenerBody body)
{
    //... method implementation
}
```

I created a custom attribute to specify the details required, but it seems I need to incorporate the `x-ms-notification-content` attribute to detail the response schema of the webhook.

How do I go about defining the `x-ms-notification-content` within the attributes to fully flesh out the trigger definition in the Swagger/OpenAPI documentation, which can then be accurately imported into the Azure custom connector?

Appreciate any guidance or examples to achieve this. Thank you!